# Is it possible to use StoreKit (In App Purchase) inside a static library?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm working on an SDK, distributed as a static library, for iOS developers to use in their apps. I'm interested in offering non-consumable downloadable and built-in content directly to users via an interface included in the SDK. Ideally, when a user buys something from my SDK's interface within one app, it would then become available to them in any other app also using the SDK. Does anyone experienced with StoreKit know if it would be possible to use Apple's In App Purchase framework to accomplish this? Would I be violating Apple's TOS if I roll my own in app purchase system?

I should add that my goal is to avoid rolling my own custom account/payment infrastructure if I can help it. Using StoreKit would be much simpler and more reliable.

**tl;dr**:

1. Is it possible to use StoreKit at all without an app ID, or using a non-deployed app ID (it looks like it might not be)?
2. Does Apple place any restrictions on custom in app purchase implementations (would I be violating the TOS)?

Comment: Why not just upload the user's device's UDID or maybe something else unique to them in the app (such as a user name or email) to a server when they purchase the product, and then in the other apps, if they are listed, then just unlock everything?

Comment: Apple is deprecating access to the UDID in iOS 5, so it will become increasingly difficult (impossible?) to uniquely identify devices across different apps. This suggestion also doesn't account for users with multiple devices.

Comment: For example, you could have the user enter in their name or email when the app starts up and store this on the server. Something to uniquely identify all of the users as an Apple ID does for Apple. This is really the only way to do it.

Comment: I updated my question with the addition that I don't want to manage user accounts myself if I can avoid it. Using StoreKit would be immensely more convenient and secure than uploading user information to my server.

Comment: Well, there's not much else I can recommend. If you can't identify a user in any way YOURSELF, then there's not much else you can do. Products IDs for in-app purchases are specific to individual apps, so those are out of the question. And apps must keeps file within their sandboxed area on iOS devices, so you can't share data among apps.

Comment: Whether or not I'm able to identify users myself is irrelevant to my question. What I'm really wondering is: 1) is it possible to use StoreKit at all without an app ID, or using a "fake" app ID (it looks like it might not be), and 2) does Apple place any restrictions on custom in app purchase implementations (would I be violating the TOS)?

Comment: @CameronSpickert let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2817/discussion-between-jack-humphries-and-cameron-spickert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I think the answer for two of your questions will be NO.

For Q1:

There is no way to do so in a SDK. Since the IAP need both product id and the App Bundle id, both of those id are unique. That means, if one of your users added the id in his iTunes Connect, no one else can use it again. And you also need to know the user's identity. This is impossible since Apple don't want developers to do so.

Of cause you can identify devices by using some unique identity of devices, but you still cannot identify a specific user. And from iOS 5, the API to get UUID is also going to be removed, it's much hard to identify a specific device.

If you are doing something that Apple do not want developers to do, I am not sure what's gonna happen.

The only thing you can do is:

> Let the user and the developer sign up to your server.
>
> The developer should tell you what id he is using for your content in his App, and what is his App bundle id.
>
> After a user bought your content, your SDK should use the App id and IAP product id to find out what the content is, and then save the information on your server.
>
> After the user login into another App, your SDK should check the server for the information. Provide the content to the user.

It sounds complex...

For Q2:

According to Apple's Review Guidelines,

```
 11. Purchasing and currencies

 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
```

It's also impossible to provide your own payment system in App Store's App.

So, basically the answer for your questions is ... NO...

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling this was a doomed idea. I didn't even think of looking at the Review Guidelines, so thanks for pointing me there. FWIW, I have seen at least one iOS SDK with a custom payment system, but it's selling real goods, not adding features.

Comment: You are welcome. I remember this review guideline because I got rejected once just because I am using a redeem code system in my App... Have to say it's hard to play with Apple but as developers we don't have other choice.